# iSCSI timeouts under high load

Tags: linux, centos, iscsi, centos6

I have two servers connected via Gigabit Ethernet. One is iSCSI target, the second one is initiator. When I run `mkfs.ext4` at initiator, after a while disk IO slows down critically in target. In the target host I can see the following in syslog:

```
Sep 14 09:40:03 sh11 tgtd: abort_task_set(1139) found 119668c 0
Sep 14 09:40:03 sh11 tgtd: abort_cmd(1115) found 119668c 6
Sep 14 09:40:03 sh11 tgtd: abort_task_set(1139) found 119668d 0
Sep 14 09:40:03 sh11 tgtd: abort_cmd(1115) found 119668d 6
Sep 14 09:40:03 sh11 tgtd: abort_task_set(1139) found 119668e 0
Sep 14 09:40:03 sh11 tgtd: abort_cmd(1115) found 119668e 6
Sep 14 09:40:03 sh11 tgtd: abort_task_set(1139) found 1196696 0
Sep 14 09:40:03 sh11 tgtd: abort_cmd(1115) found 1196696 6
Sep 14 09:40:03 sh11 tgtd: abort_task_set(1139) found 119669e 0
Sep 14 09:40:03 sh11 tgtd: abort_cmd(1115) found 119669e 6
Sep 14 09:40:04 sh11 tgtd: abort_task_set(1139) found 119669f 0
Sep 14 09:40:04 sh11 tgtd: abort_cmd(1115) found 119669f 6
```

And load average grows to 12 or even more:

```
# uptime
 12:37:00 up 23 days, 13:25,  1 user,  load average: 12.00, 7.00, 4.00
```

- CentOS 6.3
- tgtd 1.0.24
- Intel Pentium 4 2.4GHz
- 1Gb RAM
- 2Tb WD Cavlar Green SATA 2.0

> ```
> #lspci
> 00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 82845G/GL[Brookdale-G]/GE/PE DRAM Controller/Host-Hub Interface (rev 02)
> 00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82845G/GL[Brookdale-G]/GE/PE Host-to-AGP Bridge (rev 02)
> 00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801DB/DBL/DBM (ICH4/ICH4-L/ICH4-M) USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 02)
> 00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801DB/DBL/DBM (ICH4/ICH4-L/ICH4-M) USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 02)
> 00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801DB/DBL/DBM (ICH4/ICH4-L/ICH4-M) USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 02)
> 00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801DB/DBM (ICH4/ICH4-M) USB2 EHCI Controller (rev 02)
> 00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev 82)
> 00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82801DB/DBL (ICH4/ICH4-L) LPC Interface Bridge (rev 02)
> 00:1f.1 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801DB (ICH4) IDE Controller (rev 02)
> 00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 82801DB/DBL/DBM (ICH4/ICH4-L/ICH4-M) SMBus Controller (rev 02)
> 00:1f.5 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation 82801DB/DBL/DBM (ICH4/ICH4-L/ICH4-M) AC'97 Audio Controller (rev 02)
> 01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI RV200 QW [Radeon 7500]
> 02:01.0 Ethernet controller: D-Link System Inc DGE-530T Gigabit Ethernet Adapter (rev 11) (rev 11)
> 02:02.0 RAID bus controller: VIA Technologies, Inc. VT6421 IDE/SATA Controller (rev 50)
> 02:03.0 RAID bus controller: VIA Technologies, Inc. VT6421 IDE/SATA Controller (rev 50)
> 02:04.0 RAID bus controller: Silicon Image, Inc. SiI 3114 [SATALink/SATARaid] Serial ATA Controller (rev 02)
> 02:08.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82801DB PRO/100 VE (CNR) Ethernet Controller (rev 82)
> ```

Is there a way to tune target host to avoid these timeouts?

**Update**
Failing disk shows the following values:

> ```
> # smartctl -A /dev/sdb
> smartctl 5.42 2011-10-20 r3458 [i686-linux-2.6.32-279.2.1.el6.i686] (local build)
> Copyright (C) 2002-11 by Bruce Allen, http://smartmontools.sourceforge.net
>
> === START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
> SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
> Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
> ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED >     RAW_VALUE
>   1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   200   200   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
>   3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   167   167   021    Pre-fail  Always       -       6633
>   4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       93
>   5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   200   200   140    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
>   7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x002e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
>   9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   088   088   000    Old_age   Always       -       9444
>  10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   253   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
>  11 Calibration_Retry_Count 0x0032   100   253   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
>  12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       91
> 192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       64
> 193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   001   001   000    Old_age   Always       -       722663
> 194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   104   092   000    Old_age   Always       -       46
> 196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
> 197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
> 198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   200   200   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
> 199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       1
> 200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x0008   200   200   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
> ```

Comment: How about details about the hardware and disk configuration? Same for the network/switch setup

Comment: Run tgtd with --debug 10 and --foreground to see what's going in inside of tgtd.

Comment: Oh god. Caviar Green.  GLWT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that that the WD Caviar Green disk had a defect which was not detected by SMART test. After disk replacement the problem gone.

Answer (score 5):

Please note that a WD Caviar Green SATA disk is allowed to take up from 20 seconds to minutes  (or even longer) to recover from read/write errors. WD disables "time limited error recovery"(TLER) on their desktop drives. Enterprise drives from WD have 7 seconds time limit for reads and 0 seconds time limit for recovery of writes. Since you're creating a new file system with the mkfs call this will of course touch a lot of sectors on that drive some may need recovery which could be the source of the time outs.

Just to be on the safe side of things consider running `badblocks` on the backing disk of the target.

Also note that SMART may show 0 errors even if the disk is dead.

Comment: If will be much appreciated if you can provide a URL of the WD specs where this is written.

Comment: Actually this answer leaded me to check smart status of the hard drive more carefully and I found that value of Load_Cycle_Count is high. However I'm not sure if it is a problem or not.

Comment: Here's a little white paper on that topic from WD http://www.wdc.com/en/library/other/2579-001098.pdf

Answer (score 1):

If the load average is increasing on the target, you might have a disk failure (it would increase due to hardware interrupts caused by retried writes), or you may have a bug.  If it is increasing on the initiator, there could be a lot of issues, such as an issue with the iSCSI daemon or possibly a network fault.

In the past, this error message has been caused by [bugs](http://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-stgt/msg02867.html) in tgtd; consider updating if you aren't already up to date.

Comment: I checked SMART status of all the hard drives and error counters are zeros.

Comment: And as for updated, I'm using the latest CentOS 6.3, yum does not offer any additional updates.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it tries to write something sequentially. So, probably as mentioned earlier you may have some badblocks in your disk. Also, in which mode are you running your disk ? AHCI or ATA ? {You can check it in BIOS}